# Text spreading out in multicols

Tags: multicol

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}

\title{\Huge Bla bla bla}
\author{\Large John Smith}
\date{}

\fancypagestyle{amstyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Bla bla bla}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{Bla bla bla}}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{amstyle}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lettrine[lines=5]{M}{} \lipsum[1-10] 
$$\boxed{fancy equation}$$
\textit{Important sentence here}
\columnbreak
% image as large as 1 multicols \includegraphics[scale=1]{ams-add.pdf}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

The problem is the boxed equation at the end and sentence are spread out. I am unable to resolve the issue. I'd like the left column to terminate normally, and not add extra space in between.

Comment: Don't use `$$` (although it's not the source of the problem), see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503).

Comment: @egreg Yes, I usually use \newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}} and so forth, and then use \be.

Comment: Don't do that either. You gain nothing.

Comment: @egreg \begin{equation} is bad too?

Comment: Of course not! It's `\be` that's not good.

Comment: @egreg But doesn't it execute the same command? I just use \be so I don't have to type the whole thing, and \begin{...} takes space (in the source).

Comment: Yes, it's easier to type, but more difficult to *see*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the column short with `\vspace*{\fill}\null`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}

\title{Bla bla bla}
\author{John Smith}
\date{}

\fancypagestyle{amstyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Bla bla bla}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{Bla bla bla}}
    \fancyfoot[L]{\textbf{\thepage}}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{amstyle}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\lettrine[lines=5]{M}{} \lipsum[1-10] 
\[\boxed{fancy equation}\]
\textit{Important sentence here}

\vspace*{\fill}
\null
\columnbreak
% image as large as 1 multicols \includegraphics[scale=1]{ams-add.pdf}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```